# Debugging Gulpfile with node-inspector takes long to start

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, gulp, node-inspector

I am trying to debug my gulp taks with [node-inspector](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-inspector) by running it like this

```
node-debug $(which gulp) build
```

and that works, except my Gulpfile is not `.js` but `.coffee` and for some reason it hangs for almost a minute in the beginning saying:

*Requiring external module coffee-script/register*

It doesn't take that long when I run it normally and it starts node-inspector almost instantly if I use Gulpfile.js. Why is it taking too long when I use Gulpfile.coffee?

It's not a big deal, yet a bit annoying

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. Not sure why either. E.g. webpack build: 240 secs vs 30 secs when not debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Use `node-debug node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js build`

Comment: Can you explain why this would run more quickly?